# Not able to run sqoop using oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

When I am running the below sqoop command from the CLI, I am able to export data to OracleDB, But the same command when I am running using the oozie workflow , I am getting issues.

Command running directly from CLI:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.245.1:1521:XE --username HR --password HR --table HR.REVIEW_FINAL --export-dir /user/cloudera/Review/hive/review_final --input-fields-terminated-by '\001'
```

Below is what I am using through Oozie :

```
<command>export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.245.1:1521:XE --username HR --password HR --table HR.REVIEW_FINAL --export-dir /user/cloudera/Review/hive/review_final --input-fields-terminated-by '\001'</command>
```

Exception which I see in the logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data:

Comment: Are you added oracle odbc-connector jar file in oozie lib folder?

Comment: yes  I have the ojdbc6.jar file added in the sharedLib of the oozie folder

Answer (score 2):

```
--input-fields-terminated-by '\001'
```

alter it to

```
--input-fields-terminated-by \001
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, not only the input-fields-terminated-by, but also the input-null-non-string need to remove the single quote.

```
<action name="load-to-mysql">
   <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>export --connect jdbc:mysql://xtradb1.t1.shadc.yosemitecloud.com:3306/report_test --username root -password root --table location_stats --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/report/test_location_stats_${DATE} --input-null-string \\N --input-null-non-string \\N --input-fields-terminated-by \001 --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --update-mode allowinsert</command>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="remove-tmp-data"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```